# System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found

Tags: c#, excel, web-services

I am doing the server migration from windows 2003 to 2012R2 due to project needs. Application has been working fine with the old server. But, When i deployed the application in a new server, the odd parts (Part1, part3, 5,7,9, etc) are working fine. But the even parts(part2, 4,6,8, etc) are not working and showing the below error. Which means it is not hitting the web service and so showing the error. Please advice how to fix this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpg3R.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide some code samples please?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find any error with the code. It is working fine with other exports.

Comment: did you change your endpoint?

Comment: What are endpoints?